# Как ввести капчу через бота на Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

пишу бота для вк на питоне, авторизовался через аккаунт(через пользователя грубо говоря)
возникла проблема,
когда бот отправляет много сообщений, мне выдает ошибку, конкретно :

```
raise captcha vk_api.exceptions.Captcha: Captcha needed
```

так вот, поискал что-то в самих документациях от вк, но ничего не нашел

есть у кого ссылка, на конкретный пример реализации ввода капчи ботом?

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/captcha_error). Вам скорее всего придется отправить капчу пользователю, чтобы он прошел ее. Можно конечно запариться с автоматизацией... Мне кажется, не стоит оно того. Лучше объединяйте мелкие сообщения в длинные, чтобы не превышать лимит

Comment: теперь мне тоже так кажетс, ахахах